# Opening a modal using dialog API in Outlook 365 shows a "new window" alert

Tags: authentication, modal-dialog, office365, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm implementing the login system in my new Outlook 365 add-in, but I have a problem with an alert "{Addin name} wants to display a new window" shown when users try to open the modal login window. This doesn't happen in other Outlook 365 add-ins.

Following the documentation there's no mention of any restrictions: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) but it's nevertheless showing up as you can see:

[image: Warning before opening a modal login window]

I included my domain in "AppDomains" in manifest in case that's the problem, but the problem persists.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Update:** Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
export const modalLogin = () => dispatch => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(urls.login, {height: 50, width: 50},
            function (asyncResult) {
                let dialog = asyncResult.value;
                dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, (arg) => {
                    let messageFromDialog = JSON.parse(arg.message);
                    if (messageFromDialog.outcome === "success") {
                        dispatch(requestDone(resources.login, messageFromDialog.response));
                    } else {
                        dispatch(requestError(resources.login, messageFromDialog.response));
                    }
                    dialog.close();
                    resolve();
                });
            }
        );
    })
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Just set `promptBeforeOpen:false` in the `displayDialogAsync`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialogoptions?view=office-js#promptbeforeopen

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. If the page you are trying to open can open in an iframe, you should set displayInIFrame: false (default value).

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I replied to the other suggestion below, but I wonder if you know any other reasons why this might not work? (I updated the question with some code)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `displayInIframe: true` if the dialog will at any point redirect to a page that cannot be opened in an iframe.

For example, the sign in pages of many popular web services, such as Google and Microsoft Account, cannot be opened in an iframe.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I checked and we are indeed setting `displayInFrame:false` (that's the default value if you don't pass anything). In fact, if I set it to `true`, the login iframe won't even load because of security constraints. What could be other possible causes for this alert?